# MYSQL SELECT statement for selecting date period

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to retrieve data from a MYSQL database using statement but for some reasons the statement is not working as expected. What could be the reason? The values are date inputs from a form t1 and t2. Date values in the form of 2005-04-06. Could it be a date form issue? ...I am getting "No Contacts to Display" despite having data in the database. Is it syntax error?

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "ub435!";
$dbname = "funtest";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;

$t1 = $_SESSION['post-data']['t1'];
$t2 = $_SESSION['post-data']['t2'];
$time1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $t1);
$time2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $t2); 


$sql =  "SELECT DISTINCT msisdn FROM customer WHERE DATE_FORMAT(time_paid, '%Y-%c-%e') BETWEEN ADDDATE('$time1',INTERVAL 0 HOUR) AND ADDDATE('$time2',INTERVAL '23:59' HOUR_MINUTE)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo "Number of Recipients: ";  echo "$result->num_rows <br> <br>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $mobilenumber = $row['msisdn'];
      echo "Mobile : " . "$mobilenumber" . "<br>";

    }
} else {
    echo "No Contacts to Display";
}

$conn->close(); 
?>
```

Comment: Do you need generic MySQL+SQL Server solution? Why it's tagged with SQL Server?

Comment: if your issue is not fix, it may be reason of date format, please check date format in your database table and compare with $time1 and $time2

Comment: `echo` your `$sql` after preparing the query, and try executing in phpmyadmin directly, you will get a better idea of the issue. Or just paste the query here

Answer (score 1):

You've missed `$`:

```
$sql =  "SELECT DISTINCT msisdn FROM customer where time_paid  BETWEEN '$time1' AND '$time2')";
```

Comment: Avoid single quotes '$time'

Comment: @jitendrapurohit single quotes is must needed in this query.